# Disable member functions and variables without using inheritance or class specialization

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, sfinae, template-specialization

I have a template class `Foo` that comes in two variations: one has an additional template type parameter. I want the class to have some additional features when that parameter is present, namely store a member variable in the class, and provide some getters and setters for it. I also need to perform additional `static_assert()` about the additional type, I also need to disable the regular constructor and provide one that also has a parameter of that type. It looks something like this:

```
template <class Irrelevant, class Extra>
class Foo {
    //other stuff...
    static_assert(is_good_v<Extra>);
    Extra extra;
public:
    //other stuff...
    Foo(Irrelevant i) {/* irrelevant */}

    //now methods I need to enable only when Extra is present
    Foo(Irrelevant i, Extra e) : extra(e) {/* irrelevant */}
    void setExtra(Extra e) {extra = e;}
    void getExtra() {return extra;}
};
```

I've tried several approaches, but nothing seemed satisfactory. First I tried to use inheritance:

```
template <class Irrelevant>
class Bar {
    //other stuff...
public:
    //other stuff...
    Foo(Irrelevant i) {/* irrelevant */}
};

template <class Irrelevant, class Extra>
class Foo : public Bar<Irrelevant> {
    static_assert(is_good_v<Extra>);
    Extra extra;
public:
    Foo(Irrelevant i, Extra e) : Bar<Irrelevant>(i), extra(e) {/* irrelevant */}
    void setExtra(Extra e) {extra = e;}
    void getExtra() {return extra;}
};

template <class Irrelevant>
class Foo : public Bar<Irrelevant> {};
```

This (or something similar, at least) worked alone, but required extra workarounds when doing template checks on them somewhere else, also it littered the global namespace unnecessarily and I shouldn't be doing that.
The second approach was to do a specialization of `Foo`, like this:

```
template <class Irrelevant, class... T>
class Foo {};

template <class Irrelevant, class Extra>
class Foo<Irrelevant, Extra> {
    //other stuff...
    static_assert(is_good_v<Extra>);
    Extra extra;
public:
    //other stuff...
    Foo(Irrelevant i) {/* irrelevant */}

    //now methods I need to enable only when Extra is present
    Foo(Irrelevant i, Extra e) : extra(e) {/* irrelevant */}
    void setExtra(Extra e) {extra = e;}
    void getExtra() {return extra;}
};


template <class Irrelevant>
class Foo<Irrelevant> {
    //other stuff...
public:
    //other stuff...
    Foo(Irrelevant i) {/* irrelevant */}
};
```

And this also worked, and didn't litter the global namespace, but all of the `//other stuff` was duplicated, which is not that great. The third approach I wanted to try is to `std::enable_if` all of that stuff, but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried something like this:

```
template <class Irrelevant, class Extra = void>
class Foo {
    //other stuff...
    static constexpr bool hasExtra = std::is_same_v<Extra, void>;
    static_assert(!hasExtra || is_good_v<Extra>);
    std::conditional<hasExtra, Extra, bool> extra;
public:
    //other stuff...
    template <typename = typename std::enable_if_t<!hasExtra>>
    Foo(Irrelevant i) {/* irrelevant */}

    //now methods I need to enable only when Extra is present
    template <typename = typename std::enable_if_t<hasExtra>>
    Foo(Irrelevant i, Extra e) : extra(e) {/* irrelevant */}

    template <typename = typename std::enable_if_t<hasExtra>>
    void setExtra(Extra e) {extra = e;}

    template <typename = typename std::enable_if_t<hasExtra>>
    void getExtra() {return extra;}
};
```

But this obviously doesn't work since it generates a compile error as SFINAE has no other function to SFINAE its way into when compiling getters and setters. And adding dummy functions for when `Extra == void` would make code where someone uses those functions compile. How can I do that properly?

Comment: If you need _mixins_ rather use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: I could, but as I wrote, I'd prefer not to introduce any names except Foo into the global namespace.

Comment: How does that forcing to live the mixin classes in the global namespace? Just add another layer of indirection and `enable_if()` as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a `Foo` with extra only and that inherit from a partial specialization, say `Foo<Irrelevant, void>`, the common parts?

I mean: something like

```
// with extra only
template <typename Irrelevant, typename Extra>
class Foo : public Foo<Irrelevant, void>
 {
   private:
      Extra extra;

      static_assert(is_good_v<Extra>);

   public:
      // to make visible the inherited constructor(s)
      using Foo<Irrelevant, void>::Foo;

      // to disable (?) a specific inherited constructor
      // Foo(Irrelevant i) = delete;

      //now methods I need to enable only when Extra is present
      Foo(Irrelevant i, Extra e) : extra(e) {/* irrelevant */}

      void setExtra(Extra e) {extra = e;}

      Extra getExtra() {return extra;}
 };

// common part, no extra
template <typename Irrelevant>
class Foo<Irrelevant, void>
 {
   public:
      Foo(Irrelevant i) {/* irrelevant */}
 };
```

Comment: That's really nice, I didn't know a template specialization could inherit from another specialization of the same template, thanks!

Comment: @Joald - so do I: I've discovered it only a few days ago and now I'm using it extensively.